# Finding very similar program executions

Tags: c++, c, unix

I was wondering if its possible / anyone knows any tools out there to compare the execution of two related programs (for example, assignments on a class) to see how similar they are. For example, not to compare the names of functions, but how they use syscalls. One silly case of this would be testing if a C string is printed as (see example below) in more than <strike>one case</strike> one separate program.

```
printf("%s",str)
```

Or as

```
for (i=0;i<len;i++) printf("%c",str[i]);
```

I haven´t put much thought into this, but i would imagine that strace / ltrace  (maybe even oprofile) would be a good starting point. Particularly, this is for UNIX C / C++ programs.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just check the assembly code for number of branches and such.

Answer (score 1):

An initial idea would be to use ltrace and strace to log the calls and then use diff on the logs. This would obviously only cover the library an system calls. If you need a more fine granular logging, the oprofile might help.

If you have access to the source code you could instrument your code by compiling it with profiling information and then parse the gcov output after the runs. A pure static source code analysis may be sufficient if your code is not taking different routes depending on external data/state.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the source code of the two programs, you may build a graph of the functions (each function is a node, and there is an edge from A to B if A calls B()), and compute some graph similarity metrics. This will catch a source code copy made by renaming and reorganizing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this kind of thing using valgrind.

A finer-grained version (and depending on what is the access to the program source and what you exactly want in terms of comparison) would be to use kprobes.

> Kernel Dynamic Probes (Kprobes) provides a lightweight interface for kernel modules to implant probes and register corresponding probe handlers. A probe is an automated breakpoint that is implanted dynamically in executing (kernel-space) modules without the need to modify their underlying source. Probes are intended to be used as an ad hoc service aid where minimal disruption to the system is required. They are particularly advocated in production environments where the use of interactive debuggers is undesirable. Kprobes also has substantial applicability in test and development environments. During test, faults may be injected or simulated by the probing module. In development, debugging code (for example a printk) may be easily inserted without having to recompile to module under test.